# History.js hash fallbacks in Internet Explorer and pushState issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, url, pushstate, history.js

I'm implementing a web site which sets its urls dynamically using History.js when new sections are loaded to the front page via ajax.

This seems to work well but there is a problem with the hash section in the url that History.js creates as a fallback in Internet Explorer.

Here are examples of links on the page, created using jquery:

```
    function connect_browse_buttons(){
    $('.browselink').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            var action = $(this).attr('name');
            action = action.substring( ('action_browse').length );
            browsetype = action;
            if (isIE){
                // remove data object and title to avoid use of SUIDs by History.js in IE
                History.pushState(null, null, '/public/' + action);
            } else {
                History.pushState({oldurl: History.getState()['url']}, "Example " + action, config.wwwroot + "public/" + action);
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
}
```

The .htaccess file redirects any urls such as http://example.com/public/category_a to http://example.com, where the javascript parses the url and loads the appropriate section via ajax requests in the changeState handler.

The javascript checks for urls such as

```
http://example.com/public/category_a
```

AND for equivalent fallback URLs created in Internet Explorer, i.e.

```
http://example.com/#public/category_a
```

That all works OK - So:

**In Firefox**, if I open the site at the root of the site, http://example.com, and click on a link as per above, the content loads (in the changeState handler), and the url is set by History.pushState as:

```
http://example.com/public/category_a
```

If I then click on another link the url is set as, for example:

```
http://example.com/public/category_b
```

**In IE**, if I open the site at the root of the site, and click on a link, as per above, the content loads, and the url is set with a hash as:

```
http://example.com/#public/category_a
```

If I then click on the next link, the url is set as:

```
http://example.com/#public/category_b
```

**The problem arises** when I open a page in IE that was bookmarked in Firefox, and doesn't have the hash in the url. Let's take our usual example:

```
http://example.com/public/category_a
```

If I open this url directly in IE, via a bookmark or by pasting the url in the browser address bar, the .htaccess redirects successfully, the url is parsed OK by the js file and the content loads. However, now if I click on the category_b link, the url is set by History.pushState to:

```
http://example.com/public/category_a#./category_b
```

What I really wanted was to set the url as:

```
http://example.com/#public/category_b
```

However, History.js seems to take the whole of the previous url as the base url for subsequent pushStates. I have tried setting absolute urls in History.pushState but without success. As you can see in the code block above, I have an IE-specific pushState statement. I have tried configuring this in various ways. How can I get History pushState to recognize:

```
http://example.com
```

as the base part of the url, which the hash section should be appended to?
Or is there a better way to approach this than the way I describe above?

Comment: hi, did you managed to find any solutions to problem of when a page is refreshed, browser loads the first url instead of the current one??

Comment: Did you read this quesiton?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342912/using-history-pushstate-in-ie9 Maybe you can find some helpful tips

Comment: why not do pushstate to public/category_a and "redirect" to # to remove hash when pushstate works?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the history api will always use the entire URL (sans hash) that was requested for the initial page load. Once the page has loaded, you can use the history api to change what comes after that initial URL or you can use hash changes to change what comes after that initial URL, but there is no way to modify it without reloading the entire page.

The only option that I know of to achieve what you're looking for is to have your server redirect/rewrite all URLs to your desired base URL and then pass your path, filename, parameters, hash, etc through to your client side router/controller. I have to advise against this because (without too much detail) links from your website shared on Facebook will always go `http://example.com/` or whatever your base URL is.

In my opinion and in my practice, I don't use history api and instead use hash changes because it works everywhere. It's not always pretty to do, but I think you should strive to have proper web server response for URLs in addition to the hash. This is a particularly ugly URL from a website of mine: http://www.respectfulrevolution.org/road/videos/ian_barlow_finding_our_roots_forest#/road/videos/marcy_westerling_livingly_dying, but when loaded in a browser, the server responds with what you see here: http://www.respectfulrevolution.org/road/videos/ian_barlow_finding_our_roots_forest and then the client side controller loads what you see here after that: http://www.respectfulrevolution.org/#/road/videos/marcy_westering_livingly_dying
which should load the same as: http://www.respectfulrevolution.org/road/videos/marcy_westering_livingly_dying