# Using history.pushstate in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-9, pushstate

Since window.history.pushState is not aviliable for HTML 4 browsers like IE9 , I have looked for history.js, a jQuery library that simulates the pushState behavior.

The problem is , when using pushState, the end of the url is duplicated

For example,

```
History.pushState(null,null,window.location.pathname + '?page=1');
```

returns,

http://www.development.com/test.html#test.html?page=1

How do I avoid this problem? Thank you kindly.

**Update (On 2012 / 1 /22)  , Question for bounty:**

```
                if (pageNo == 1){
                    //window.history.pushState({"html":currURL,"pageTitle":''},"", window.location.pathname + '?page=1'); For chrome and FX only
                    //History.replaceState(null,null,'')
                    //History.pushState(null,null,'?issue=' + currPageIssueNo + '&page=1');
                }   
                else if (pageNo != 1 || pageNo == 1 && linkPageNo > 1  ) {
                    History.pushState(null,null,'?issue=' + currPageIssueNo + '&page=' + pageNo);
                    //window.history.pushState({"html":currURL,"pageTitle":''},"", newURL);   For chrome and FX only
                }
```

I am still encounter the problem , if it is the first page

```
http://localhost/development/flipV5.html?issue=20121220&page=1
```

When i go to second page in IE9 , it has url :

```
http://localhost/development/flipV5.html?issue=20121220&page=1#flipV5.html?issue=20121220&page=2
```

Which i would like to achieve is

```
http://localhost/development/flipV5.html?issue=20121220&page=2
```

If it is impossible for HTML 4 browser, please  at least achieve

```
http://localhost/development/flipV5.html/#?issue=20121220&page=2
```

thanks for kindly help

Comment: 'test.html' , ideally, should be http://www.development.com/test.htm;?page=1 is perfect, but it seems not possible

Comment: This is the demo http://balupton.github.com/history.js/demo/?state=4

Comment: Try it as http://balupton.github.com/history.js/demo/#?state=4

Comment: Since IE9 doesn't support `pushState`, it's emulated by using `onhashchange`.  That means it's (probably) supposed to add the `#test.html` to the URL.

Comment: thanks, would you mind look at updated question?

Answer (score 3):

Your code does exactly what you'd expect it to.

```
window.location.pathname + '?page=1'
```

Prints out the location pathname (`test.html`), and appends `?page=1`

Remove `window.location.pathname` and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up a client-side redirect for IE.  Assuming the user lands at this page:

```
http://localhost/development/flipV5.html?issue=20121220&page=1
```

They need to be sent to

```
http://localhost/development/flipV5.html#?issue=20121220&page=1
```

The reason is that IE <= 9 doesn't let you modify anything before the hash, without sending the user to a new page.  It's an old security feature preventing changing the URL to `facebook.com`, when you're really on `spambook.com`.  Recently, people have realized that that's overkill.

The redirect looks like this:

```
<!--[if LTE IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (location.search) 
    location.href = location.pathname + "#" + location.search;
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

You can now push states, and they won't show up in both the search and the hash (that's after the `?` and `#` respectively)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove window.location.pathname from `History.pushState`

```
History.pushState(null,null,'?page=1');
```

Comment: It looks like this is using the history.js api on the client

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
History.replaceState(null,null,'?issue=' + currPageIssueNo + '&page=' + pageNo);
```

Comment: It looks like this is using the history.js api on the client