# History.pushState in IE9 adding Hash tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, history.js

I am using history.js for IE support. But History.pushState appending extra #data in URL. How to fix this?

Chrome URL

```
http://localhost/shop/contracts-and-deals/mobile-phones?&_dyncharset=ISO-8859-1&_dynSessConf=8052455241245685514&planItemSkuId=&device=phones&contractType=onAccount&_D%3AcontractType=+&manufactureFilter=800005&_D%3AmanufactureFilter=+&_DARGS=%2Fshop%2FmobilePhones%2Fphones%2Ffilters%2FphonesLeftPanel.jsp&_dyncharset=ISO-8859-1&_dynSessConf=8052455241245685514&_D%3AsortFilter=+&sortFilter=most_popular&sort-view=grid&_DARGS=%2Fshop%2FmobilePhones%2Fphones%2Ffilters%2FdeviceTopFilter.jsp
```

Internet Explorer URL

```
http://localhost/shop/contracts-and-deals/mobile-phones#mobile-phones?&_dyncharset=ISO-8859-1&_dynSessConf=8052455241245685514&planItemSkuId=&device=phones&contractType=onAccount&_D%3AcontractType=+&manufactureFilter=800005&_D%3AmanufactureFilter=+&_DARGS=/shop/mobilePhones/phones/filters/phonesLeftPanel.jsp&_dyncharset=ISO-8859-1&_dynSessConf=8052455241245685514&_D%3AsortFilter=+&sortFilter=most_popular&sort-view=grid&_DARGS=/shop/mobilePhones/phones/filters/deviceTopFilter.jsp
```

Extra `#mobile-phones` getting appended after using History.pushState in Internet Explorer.

I Have tried below code.

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var urlparts = url.split('/');
var currentState = urlparts[urlparts.length-1];

if(f && f != 'undefined' && f.hasClass('filterParams')) {
    var atgPrefix = "_D%3A";
    var totalParams = b.data;
    var arrayOfParams = totalParams.split("&");
    var paramSize = arrayOfParams.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < paramSize;i++){
            if(arrayOfParams[i].indexOf(atgPrefix) != -1) {
                var inputField = arrayOfParams[i].substring(arrayOfParams[i].indexOf(atgPrefix)+atgPrefix.length).split("=")[0];
                if(totalParams.indexOf("&"+inputField) == -1) {
                    totalParams = totalParams.replace(arrayOfParams[i]+"&",'');
                } else {
                    var atgHiddenFields = totalParams.match(new RegExp(arrayOfParams[i], 'g'));
                    var size = atgHiddenFields.length-1; 
                    for(var j = 0;j < size;j++) {
                        totalParams = totalParams.replace(arrayOfParams[i]+"&",'');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        b.data = totalParams;
}
if(!($(a).closest('form').is('#colorPicker'))){
    if ( document.location.protocol === 'file:' ) {
        alert('The HTML5 History API (and thus History.js) do not work on files, please upload it to a server.');
    }
    var History = window.History, // Note: We are using a capital H instead of a lower h
    State = History.getState(),
    $log = $('#log');

    // Log Initial State
    History.log('initial:', State.data, State.title, State.url);

    // Bind to State Change
    History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
        // Log the State
        var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state
        History.log('statechange:', State.data, State.title, State.url);

    });
    History.pushState(b.data, document.title, currentState+"?"+b.data);
}
```

I have also tried with [Using history.pushstate in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342912/using-history-pushstate-in-ie9) but with no luck.

Comment: I don't think you can. IE9 doesn't support history API. That's why libraries are using hashchange event to emulate it.

Comment: I know IE9 doesn't support history API, that's why I am trying to use history.js

Comment: Which in its turn uses hashchange event to emulate history API making changes to location.hash unavoidable.

Comment: Same problem here. I am also looking for a solution to this.

Comment: Your URL is so massive already - why bother with an extra hashtag?

Answer (score 3):

If we refer to the official documentation on the [history.js GitHub repository](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/), we will find the following documentation on this issue.

Under the **Aims** section, we find that history.js resolves differences in HTML5 browsers.

> Provide a cross-compatible experience for all HTML5 Browsers

But uses a hash-fallback for HTML4 browsers.

> Provide a backwards-compatible experience for all HTML4 Browsers using a hash-fallback

The use of the terms "HTML5 Browser" and "HTML4 Browser" are a bit of a misnomer here, as it is not an an issue of the browser supporting HTML5, but the implementation of the session history API.

Checking the [caniuse page for the session history API](http://caniuse.com/history) shows us that Internet Explorer 10 was the first version of Internet Explorer to implement this API, so for older versions history.js instead must use the hash-fallback. The **Browsers: Tested and Working In** section of the GitHub repository confirms this.

> **HTML5 Browsers**
>
> - Firefox 4+
> - Chrome 8+
> - Opera 11.5+
> - Safari 5.0+
> - Safari iOS 4.3+
>
> **HTML4 Browsers**
>
> - IE 6, 7, 8, 9, (10)
> - Firefox 3
> - Opera 10, 11.0
> - Safari 4
> - Safari iOS 4.2, 4.1, 4.0, 3.2

Oddly enough, it seems to list Internet Explorer 10 under HTML4 browsers even though IE10 does have the session history API. In my own testing, history.js does use the session history API in IE10, and not the hash-fallback. I believe this section of documentation has not be updated since the release of IE10 and refers to a pre-release version of IE10.

In the examples, we can see how using `History.pushState` might look in an browser that supports the session history API.

```
www.mysite.com/?state=1
```

Versus how it would look in a browser that must instead use the hash-fallback.

```
www.mysite.com/#?state=1&_suid=1
```

## In Conclusion

history.js is working exactly as expected in Internet Explorer 9. IE9 does not implement the session history API, thus history.js is instead using the URL hash as a substitute for this missing feature. The only way to prevent history.js from appending a hash would be to not call `History.pushState` or any related API's unless the browser supports the history API. Obviously, doing this removes most of the benefits provided by history.js, but if you want to detect support for the session history API, you can use the `History.emulated.pushState` property provided by history.js.

```
if(!History.emulated.pushState)
{
    //Uses session history API.
}else{
    //Uses hash-fallback.
}
```